# Download a partir de link com download automático e salvar mudando diretório no R

Tags: r, pdf

Tenho uma lista de links que fazem download automático de arquivos pdf e gostaria de salvá-los com um nome novo em uma pasta que eu criei com o dir.create().

Pensei em originalmente importar o arquivo como um objeto do R mas o pdf não está disponível online, só para download. Também não consegui mudar as configurações de download com o download.file().

Um pedaço do meu código:

```
i <- "/consulta/dowload-arquivo-anexado/id/1229" 
#isso aqui vai ser um loop futuramente, por isso esse i

#url do documento
url2 <- paste0("http://oportunidades.mda.gov.br" , i)

#criando diretório que eu irei salvar meu documento
pasta <- gsub('.*/ ?(\\w+)', '\\1', i)
dir.create(paste0(dir_base, pasta))
destino <- paste0(dir_base, pasta)

#o que não deu certo   
download.file(url= url2,
              destfile= destino)
[1]Error in download.file(url = url2, destfile = destino) : cannot open destfile '.Documents/1229', reason 'Permission denied'
```

Agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: o problema apontado pelo R é a permissão da pasta ".Documents", tem certeza que esta é a pasta que em deseja salvar o arquivo? (com o `.` antes de `Documents`)

Comment: Fornecer o conteúdo de `dir_base` pode ajudar.

Comment: Acabei deletando a parte que eu crio o dir_bases. É dir_base <- "C:/Users/coliv/Documents/" , só uma pasta base para criar os demais diretórios.

Comment: eu mudeu o texto da pasta de documentos só pra deixar mais limpo. Ele aponta uma pasta que existe mesmo.

Comment: E o erro continua o mesmo?

Comment: sim, o erro permanece o mesmo

Comment: Tenta redefinir o `destino` antes. Assim `destino <- paste0(dir_base, pasta, "download.pdf")`. E depois rodar de novo a linha que faz o download

Comment: @TomásBarcellos funcionou! Além disso eu também precisei inserir o parâmetro method = "curl" . Muito obrigada!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro estava acontecendo porque o conteúdo de `destino` era uma pasta e não o nome de um arquivo. Mudar `destino` para

```
destino <- paste0(dir_base, pasta, "/download.pdf")
destino
# [1] ".Documents/1229/download.pdf"
```

corrige o problema ao apontar para um arquivo e não uma pasta.